# Why is my Word document being cropped when I print?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2007

I'm trying to create a landscape A3 (42.0 x 29.7cm) table plan for a wedding in Microsoft Word 2007. (Yes, I know it's not the best tool for the job, but it's all I've got and it's what I know best. I'm also aware that my design lacks a certain flourish. ;)

My problem is that when I print the document to PDF to take to a professional print company, the top and bottom of the page are missing.

Here's how the document looks while editing it:

[image: As seen during editing]

And here's how it looks when I go to print preview:

[image: As seen in Print Preview]

As far as I'm concerned, I really don't think I've done anything weird to create this document. I've:

- Set the page color
- Set a page border
- Added a light cream-coloured rectangle and sent it to back
- Added a few other shapes and text boxes for the room layout and heading
- Added another text box and put a table in it with all guests' names

And that's all. None of the text boxes or shapes lies outside of the page and the page margins remain set to Normal.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to fix it, please?

Thanks. :)

**Update:**
I've just loaded the exact same file into Word 2007 on a different computer and, this time, the PDF has been produced correctly i.e. without any cropping. So, it seems there's nothing wrong with the document *per se*, but that it's more likely the way printers are set up on the different machines (as suggested in by both respondents so far).

Comment: What happens when you simply `Save As PDF`? Does it also crop?

Comment: @Randolph Yeah, exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to explain, but it's cropping text blocks or table rows that fall anywhere near the page borders, even if they're slightly over, and then the whole lot is chopped off.

This may be printer settings, but it could also be page layout settings.

Have a look at margins, paper size, etc., making sure that the printer is set to print to A3 (or whatever).

I've seen this happen with Letter vs A4 size, so I think it's the same issue. Usually it's printer settings, trying to print to a size that isn't what you think it is.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you adjusted the page layout settings of the document?

Word will not print anything that falls outside the range of the page margins.  Set custom page margins to zero and try printing again.  Disabling headers and footers also might have the same effect; every time I have used custom page margins I have disabled them and my docs all print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in MS Word 2012 and after several trials and errors found the reason. Whenever I added the image to the document using drag-and-drop and print the document, it would cut off the image and scale it. Exactly the same as the image above. You should insert the image using the insert menu. This way word creates an image object that you can for example rotate and scale.
This looks like a bug to me but I don't think reporting it to Microsoft will actually resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found to this was to save the doc and open it in Google Docs, save it in Google Docs in the format you want then download it as a Word doc and reopen it in Word.

I had 2 images in my Word doc that kept cutting off when printing, they were in the middle of the page so it wasn't the margins and even if I resized the image really large or really small it still cut off the image when printing.  I had 4 other images in the document that were printing fine.

I opened the file in Google Docs, formatted to my liking, downloaded it as a Word doc then opened the new file in Word and it printed perfectly.